# Display "Available for Reservation" in a slot that is not an Event and is not a BusinessHour in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

We are building a reservation system with Fullcalendar in React.
We are using timeGridPlugin and would like to display "Available for Reservation" for slots that have no Event and no BusinessHour.
How can I achieve this?

I tried the following code but only one column today is ⚪︎. The expectation is to make all the places that are not applicable to either Event or BusinessHour to be ⚪︎.

```
  const slotLaneContent = (arg: SlotLaneContentArg) => {
    console.log(arg);
    if (true) {
      return (
        <>⚪︎</>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  <FullCalendar
    slotLaneContent={slotLaneContent}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMOn1.png)

Comment: You can't really - there's no hook in the API to identify a specific slot, and if you examine the HTML you'll see that the rows and columns are actually constructed using two separate tables. So there's no physical space you can put the information into. Just add a key or some explanation above the calendar to indicate that all unoccupied areas are available to reserve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems impossible after all.