# FullCalendar - How to add content to hour cell?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is it possible to add content to each cell in timeGridWeek View and timeGridDay?

In dayGridMonth I could use something like this:

```
dayCellContent: function(arg){
let html = '';
if(!arg.isPast) 
html = '<a title="Add meeting"  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="displayEventAdd(' + arg.date.getTime() + '); return false;" class="addEventButton">
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>';
                                            
return {html: html + arg.dayNumberText, textEscape: false}; 
}
```

[image: Effect of dayCellContent in MonthView]

How can I add additional content in timegrid views?

Effect that I need in Week view:
[image: Effect that I need in Week view]

Effect that I need in Day view:
[image: Effect that I need in Day view]

I cannot see anything in documentation. Didn't found anything similar to dayCellContent (timeCellContent or hourCellContent).

Comment: See comments on this thread from a few days ago which asked almost exactly the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672910/display-available-for-reservation-in-a-slot-that-is-not-an-event-and-is-not-a